# Postgres: Making column in first row contain sum of same column in other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm a newbie in postgres and i have a troubling issue.
Suppose the output of my SQL query is

```
123456789;"2014-11-20 12:30:35.454875";500;200;"2014-11-16 16:16:26.976258";300
123456789;"2014-11-20 12:30:35.454875";500;200;"2014-11-16 16:16:27.173523";100
```

What i want is to sum up all the 4th column, and so that the first row will contain the sum of the 4th column

```
123456789;"2014-11-20 12:30:35.454875";500;400;"2014-11-16 16:16:26.976258";300
```

My query is

```
select l.phone_no, l.loan_time, l.cents_loaned/100, r.cents_deducted/100, r.event_time, 
r.cents_balance/100
from tbl_table1 l
LEFT JOIN tbl_table2 r
ON l.tb1_id = r.tbl2_id
where l.phone_no=123456789
order by r.event_time desc
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And what should be the content of the other columns? From any other row or from a specific one?

Comment: Other columns will have the contents of the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps. It will add a new row containing the sum of the 4th column.

```
WITH query AS (
  SELECT l.phone_no, l.loan_time, l.cents_loaned/100 AS cents_loaned, 
         r.cents_deducted/100 AS cents_deducted, r.event_time, 
         r.cents_balance/100 AS cents_balance,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.event_time DESC) rn,
         SUM(cents_deducted/100) OVER () AS sum_cents_deducted
    FROM tbl_table1 l
    LEFT 
    JOIN tbl_table2 r
      ON l.tb1_id = r.tbl2_id
   WHERE l.phone_no=123456789
)
SELECT phone_no, loan_time, cents_loaned, cents_deducted, event_time, cents_balance
  FROM query
 WHERE rn > 1
 UNION
   ALL 
SELECT phone_no, loan_time, cents_loaned, sum_cents_deducted, event_time, cents_balance
  FROM query
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm, however, i removed     'SELECT phone_no, loan_time, cents_loaned, cents_deducted, event_time, cents_balance
  FROM query
 WHERE rn > 1
 UNION
   ALL' from the query

Answer (score 0):

Use a [**window function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html) over the whole set (`OVER ()`) as frame:

```
select l.phone_no, l.loan_time, l.cents_loaned/100
     , sum(r.cents_deducted) OVER () / 100 AS total_cents_deducted
     , r.event_time, r.cents_balance/100
FROM   tbl_table1 l
LEFT   JOIN tbl_table2 r ON l.tb1_id = r.tbl2_id
WHERE  l.phone_no = 123456789
ORDER  BY r.event_time desc
```

This will return *all* rows, not just the first. Your question is unclear as to that.